# JSON Encoded data not accessible

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I queried the data from database using a Model.

```
echo $user = User::whereRaw('username = ? and password = ?', array($username,$password))->get();
```

The output is in JSON format

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Abhijith","username":"abhi","created_at":"2014-07-31 20:07:35","updated_at":"2014-07-31 20:07:35"}]
```

But when I try to echo a single field, I get an index not found error.

```
echo $user->id; //Gives an error saying the index is not found
```

Comment: are you getting an actual string of json data? If so you would need to json_decode it to turn it into a php object that you can access or else it is just a string.

Comment: You have to decode the json object like [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) with json_decode

Comment: `echo $user[0]->id;` Look at the object, it makes sense. Taking away this superfluous up-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get in the habit of looking at the structure and not assuming.  Also, you need to `json_decode` the string.  Then use `print_r` to see the structure:

```
$result = json_decode($user);
echo $result[0]->id;
```

Or (PHP >= 5.4.0 I think):

```
echo json_decode($user)[0]->id;
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. All I had to do was
echo $result[0]->id;

Comment: Note: you didn't need to json_decode it. It's only JSON because it was echo'd (it has a magic method for when it is used as a string), its actually an object that can naturally be accessed with `$user[0]->id`

Comment: @Someguy123:  Good to know.  I'm not a laravel guy.